# jquery initialising tinymce but it does not display on page

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I have referenced the javascript file in the head of my layout page.

I initialized tinymce and choose my element id, and set the height of the text area.

The text area height does change when I change it in the init, but the actual text area is set to `style="display: none;"` when I inspect the page.

Anyone have any ideas why this is happening and what i can do to fix it?

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: '#mytextarea',
  height: 100
});
```

When I change the height, it alters the height of my div, but the actual text area does not display.

Answer (score 0):

for anyone having the same problem as this, the javascript file that was included in the download was knackered

when i referenced the file that was on their site, it worked fine